# React-native listview image rerender loosing clickhandlers

Tags: android, image, listview, react-native

I have a listView.

In each row there is an Image component with a key the same as the URI. 
Nested in the Image components there are a couple of elements, one of those are a touchableHighlight that you can press.

I do some sorting on the dataSource, and first some of the nested elements disappeared when it re-rendered, but that stopped happening after i inserted the key prop on the image.

Now however if a row changes place during rerender the button inside the Image component stops working.

Cant fint any good information, but my guess is that when having a key on the image React just rerenders what it had in the virtual dom, and does not care about reattaching event listeners.

Does someone have any good information what happens to a Image component inside a listView row with a key prop attached to it when it rerenders.